# How to center a wide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is what I had tried:

```js
(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

```css
.fb-comments{
        display:block;     
        margin:25px auto;
     background:gold;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://dubina.net16.net/comments.php" data-numposts="100"></div>
```

The div is not centered, but aligned to the left side!
I want to put it in the center of the page.

Comment: what is the wrapper div/element?

Comment: @link2pk, see my update, pls

Comment: I think you need to add text-align:center; to your body element like  http://jsfiddle.net/KcBHd/592/

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `min-width` and `min-height`/`width: auto;` properties in your CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

```
.fb-comments{
    display:block;      
    margin:auto;
    background:gold;
}
```

Another way is to
make it a child of the **HTML** document directly, without being in a `<div>` or something.
Then add css `left:50%;` or `right:50%;` , there is a difference between them, but it works. Then add `position:absolute;` to make it position relative to the ancestor, which is the **HTML** document in your case.

---

**EDIT :**
I can tell you why it's not working. First, If you tried `left:50%;` , Your comment box left edge will start at the middle of the screen causing it to be rendered from 50% to the right, So, The beginning only is at 50%, not the whole `<div>`

**And :** to fix this, You can use [This](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/GbDw9/) but it will use jQuery, Not HTML/CSS only.

**OR :** use this

```
.fb-comments {
    position: block;
    width:545px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    top:150px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

Be sure to change `top:150px;` to suit your needs.

---

**EDIT :**I'm not a JavaScript programmer, but I understand the basics, I tell how how to do it. without css (as my answer above worked with me)
The problem is, centering a div always puts the first pixel column in the center, You div is really centered, but related to his left pixels, no the middle. 
Your solution will be in Javascript & a photo editing app, it's not a practical solution, but it works.

- Get the width of your picture or div and type it somewhere. (with the photo editing app)
- Now, Center it as you did.
- It will be centered related to it's left pixels not the center
- in JavaScript, add the picture width/2 from the right/left margins depends on what's nearer to the edge.
  This is not a practical solution & in most cases, It will not work because you will be doing a media rule for every resolution to make it perfect.

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexbox, and wrap it to a container div. if you set the display and properties of that "container div" as :

```
.fb-comments-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

the div inside this is going to be centered. And you can update .fb-comments as :

```
.fb-comments {
  display: flex;
  margin: 25px 0;
  background: gold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class .fb-comments seems to be overtaken by another fb class that's loading ".fb_iframe_widget_loader". So you need to add another selector to your class like below. If you want the element to take up the whole screen use display: block;, but if you want it to center then use display: inline-block; and add text-align: center; to the parent container. In this case it's the body.

```js
(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

```css
    body {
        text-align: center;
    }
    body .fb-comments{
        display: inline-block;     
        margin:25px auto;
     background: gold;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://dubina.net16.net/comments.php" data-numposts="100"></div>
```

Comment: Another fun way to center things is to put them into a div with position relative and the child can be position absolute with top, bottom, left, right all set to zero and then margin set to auto. Like this codepen: https://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt

Answer (score 0):

add `position: relative` to the CSS of the *parent* element (i.e. the container) of `fb-comments` - only then the `margin: 25px auto;` setting can center the div.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better give the complete code.Take second div as an example，if it's parentNode is body，you need to set the width and height，if it's parentNode is not body,you can do like this：

```
.fb-comments{
        width:800px;
        height:800px;
        display:block;      
        margin:25px auto;
        background:gold;
        **position:absolute;**
    }
$(function()
    {
        var $lol = $("#lol");
        $lol.css("left",(window.innerWidth-$lol[0].offsetWidth)/2);
        $lol.css("top",(window.innerHeight-$lol[0].offsetHeight)/2);
    })
  <div id="lol" class="fb-comments" data-href="http://dubina.net16.net/comments.php" data-numposts="100"></div>
```